# How to test an auto complete textbox using selenium c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have tried many solutions present in this site. But none of it worked. I wanted a simple code using " keys.enter " . Can someone help me out with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you.Here you are opening facebook, and trying to login.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.List;

public class TestCase {
    private static WebElement element;
    static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String URL = "https://www.facebook.com/";
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(URL);
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    }
}
```